# How to use url rewriting on Azure website with PHP

Tags: php, windows, azure

I would like to use url rewritting on Azure Web sites, with my php web site, but I don't know how i can do it.
If someone can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use URL-Rewrite module (which is installed and active on Azure Web Sites by default) to write URL-Rewrite rules.

Checkout this site to start.  You will have to create your rules in a web.config file that you can place along side your PHP web site.

http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module

If you have more specific questions about specific rewrite rules you want to write, I would try searching StackOverflow since it is a common question in general.